# I need help converting this svelte code to react.js

Tags: reactjs, svelte

I found this code svelte code snippet online and i have been trying to recreate it in react.js, i know it has something to do with componentDidMount(), but im not sure on how to go about it.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import { getETHPrice } from "../utils/getETHPrice";
    let value;
    onMount(async () => {
        value = await getETHPrice();
    });
</script>

<h1>Current Data Feed for MATIC/USD</h1>
<p>
    $ {(1 * value).toFixed(2)} USD
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount effects in functional components are effects with no dependencies:

```
const P = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getETHPrice().then(setValue);
  }, []);

  return <><h1><p>{`${(value||0).toFixed(2)}USD`}</p></h1></>;
}
```

Comment: the code isn't rendering anything, i used the code exactly how you suggested

Comment: @Emmanuel you did put some actual code inside the `h1` tags, right?

Comment: @ThomasHennes yes I did and my console was going crazy all red

Comment: The point here is that `useEffect(() => {}, [])` is code that will only run once on mount. Are you trying to use useEffect in a class component? If you share your code and errors here I can help ;)

Comment: I didn't use it in a class component, I did it exactly how you told me, I didn't receive any errors in the vs code, just that in my local server it isn't displaying anything. @windowsill

Comment: react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <App> component:

    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

@windowsill

Comment: Uncaught Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
    at reconcileChildFibers (bundle.js:43679:27)
    at reconcileChildren (bundle.js:46456:32)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:47319:9)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:48447:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:33436:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:33485:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:33545:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:53287:11)
@windowsill

Comment: This isn't related to the question anymore, because the above code definitely works. But if you want help *please*, please show all your react code.